# Ошибка при попытке загрузки модели: CatboostError: util/ysaveload.h:70: can not load pod array(827146819, 2028140 bytes)

Tags: python, catboost

Код:

```
CatBoostClassifier.load_model(mod, fname = 'model_final.sav')
```

Ошибка:

```
CatboostError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-30737d297805> in <module>()
----> 1 CatBoostClassifier.load_model(mod, fname = 'model_final.sav')

/opt/anaconda3/envs/anaconda3_catboost0_2_2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/catboost/core.py in load_model(self, fname)
    671         if not isinstance(fname, STRING_TYPES):
    672             raise CatboostError("Invalid fname type={}: must be str().".format(type(fname)))
--> 673         self._load_model(fname)
    674         return self
    675 

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._CatBoostBase._load_model (/home/donskov/.ya/build/build_root/oc50/00034f/catboost/python-package/catboost/_catboost.pyx.cpp:16038)()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._CatBoost._load_model (/home/donskov/.ya/build/build_root/oc50/00034f/catboost/python-package/catboost/_catboost.pyx.cpp:11986)()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._CatBoost._load_model (/home/donskov/.ya/build/build_root/oc50/00034f/catboost/python-package/catboost/_catboost.pyx.cpp:11923)()

CatboostError: util/ysaveload.h:70: can not load pod array(827146819, 2028140 bytes)
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос (кнопка `править`) версию библиотеки и питона

Comment: А какое значение находится в `mod`?

Comment: mod = CatBoostClassifier()

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
CatBoostClassifier.load_model('model_final.sav', mod)
```

У `load_model` такая [семантика](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/b89cec3f467e62dfb1f0667e4aeadc3faff74347/catboost/python-package/catboost/core.py#L1614): `def load_model(self, fname, format='catboost'):`, поэтому я думаю, что вы перепутали параметры.

**UPD.**

Меня код в вопросе смущает, думаю моя подсказка не поможет, т.к. `load_model` не статичный метод.

Правильно будет так:

```
model = CatBoostClassifier()
model.load_model('model_final.sav')
```

**PS.**

Пример API: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/catboost/CatboostModelAPI.md

Comment: Возникает та же ошибка. :(

Comment: @Александра, на оба варианта, что я показывал в ответе? Не верю

Comment: Извините, не увидела.

Comment: На вариант CatBoostClassifier.load_model('model_final.sav', mod)  возникает Invalid fname type=<class 'catboost.core.CatBoostClassifier'>: must be str().

Comment: @Александра, ну, я так и думал, что это модель :) т.к. `mod` мало походил названием на `format`. Поэтому, и написал второй вариант после UPD. В вашем случае, соответственно, будет `mod.load_model('model_final.sav')`. Но я бы рекомендовал писать полное название, т.к. есть такая операция mod для получения остатка от деления, путать будет )

Comment: Да, это модель. На эту строку mod.load_model('model_final.sav') возникает такая же ошибка CatboostError: util/ysaveload.h:70: can not load pod array(827146819, 2028140 bytes) :((

Comment: @Александра, хмм а ну да... если ту функцию объекта `def load_model(self, fname, format='catboost')` вызвать как у вас в вопросе `CatBoostClassifier.load_model(mod, fname = 'model_final.sav')`, то в `self` попадет объекта модели и это будет эквиваленто тому, что я в ответе написал. Будет тоже самое, но запутанное, через одно место :) Похоже, проблема в модели `model_final.sav`, кст вот код, что ту ошибку писал: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/d5b064ab7deb5fbb11af9d48495d5c7b2cb02a21/util/ysaveload.h#L72